# Why do digest and PKI.digest return different hash?

Tags: r, pki, digest

For example. When I calculate a hash with each functions I get different result.

```
PKI::PKI.digest("hola", "MD5")
```

```
digest::digest("hola", "md5")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `serialize = FALSE` for `digest`.

```
> PKI::PKI.digest("hola", "MD5")
 [1] 4d 18 63 21 c1 a7 f0 f3 54 b2 97 e8 91 4a b2 40
> digest::digest("hola", "md5", serialize=FALSE)
[1] "4d186321c1a7f0f354b297e8914ab240"
```

The help page of `digest` states that the input is serialized by default.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself :)